# Making a script to open, configure, and run multiple programs sequentially

Tags: windows, scripting

While I have experience coding in Java and c++, I have never scripted anything and would like to learn. I want to create a script or a program which:

```
Opens Avast Virus Scanner
    -deep scans
    -quits upon being completed
Opens Malwarebytes
    -same as above
opens Spybot Search & Destroy
    -same as above
Shuts down computer
```

I honestly don't know where to even start - should I use a batch file or something else? I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: You could also look into using VBScript instead of a batch file, though I think either should work.

Comment: Find out if your programs have command lines that run your programs in the way you want, as sometimes only the paid versions have unrestricted command line interfaces.  You would put the three command lines in a batch file using the `start "" /wait command ...' format and add the shutdown command.

Answer (score 9):

This is only a partial answer, but in order to open programs, you can write a batch file. I found this guide: http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/create-windows-batch-files/

```
@echo off
start "Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
start "Notepad" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
start "VS2012" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
start "Outlook" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\outlook.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically you don't have to touch coding.  This can be done through "scheduling" or through some free software.  Is it completely necessary to do the coding yourself?